# Read data from MySQL via AJAX to be sent as data object in the controller of NVD3-Angular

Tags: angularjs, ajax, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives, angular-nvd3

I have found the library [nvD3-Angular](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) which looks really good and friendly.
I am using it to plot just static data, but I want to be able to read data stored in my DB. Is there a way to set up the data variable with the mentioned data via AJAX using JQuery?? 
I know there must be a way to fetch this data, nut I have not found it yet.

My code is as follows:
In my html:

```
<div ng-controller="PlotController">
    <nvd3 options="options" data="data">
    </nvd3>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
app.controller('PlotController', function($scope){
        /* Chart options */
        $scope.options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'cumulativeLineChart',
                height: 450,
                margin : {
                    ...
                },
            }
        };
        $scope.initData = [
            {
                key: "Cis ON",
                mean: 250,
                values: [ [ 1083297600000 , -2.974623048543] , ... , [ 1354251600000 , 349.45128876100]]
            },
            {
                key: "Cis OFF",
                mean: -60,
                values: [ [ 1083297600000 , -0.77078283705125] ,..., [ 1085976000000 , -1.8356366650335]]
            },
        ]; 
        //Chart data
        $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.initData);
});
```

As extra info: 
Server side is coded with Php Laravel 5.1, using mysql as the DB.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I want to deliver in my app the formatted data to be injected inside the values of $scope.data. How can this be done? I know it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer `$http` service in angularjs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Sample:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'your api url'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
  // when the response is available
}).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
  // called asynchronously if an error occurs
  // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: Yes, just to clarify, I am not reffering to the data in $http, but I want to set the content of $scope.data in the object used by PlotController in nvD3.

Comment: Do you haveany exposed api to fetch the data from?

Comment: No, it would need to be done manually from what I understand.

Comment: Yeah. What is the url for that?

Comment: It is local, on server side in routes I have: `Route::get('/read_allegro', 'FileController@read'); `and inside that     `public function read()
    {
        // Validate the request..

        $measurementSection = new AllegroFileHandler();
        $data = $measurementSection->find(4)->get();

        return response($data);

    }`

Comment: I understand why you have sent me to the $http documentation. It is a good idea to work with promises in this case, I will be researching to solve the problem.